# about map and area tag

Tags: javascript, html

Area tag don't work in my html codes.

```html
 <!--images-->
    <img
      align="center"
      src="C:\Users\RS\Pictures\fotoshop\ananimous.png"
      alt="ananimouse"
      width="750"
      usemap="hacker"
    />
    <!--map . with using image-map.net-->
    <map name="hacker">
      <area
        target="_blank"
        alt="anonymouse"
        title="anonymouse"
        href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_(hacker_group)"
        coords="785,495,501,614"
        shape="rect"
      />
      />
    </map>
```

Comment: Please provide a real [mcve]. Use the stack snippets feature to provide a live demo. Use a service like http://placekitten.com/ to provide a real image (we can't access your C drive!!)

Comment: Do [basic automated testing](https://validator.nu/) as you have several errors it will pick up.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#` in the beginning of the image name.

```html
<img
      align="center"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
      alt="ananimouse"
      width="750"
      usemap="#hacker"
    />
    <!--map . with using image-map.net-->
    <map name="hacker">
      <area
        target="_blank"
        alt="anonymouse"
        title="anonymouse"
        href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_(hacker_group)"
        coords="785,495,501,614"
        shape="rect"
      />
    </map>
```